# How to increase Memory?

Tags: mantras, smriti, saraswati, mind, consciousness

Is there any practice, mantra/stotra in Hinduism to Increase Memory.

I want to read about Smriti-Sakti, Jnana-Sakti, Buddhi Sakti, Kalpana Sakti, Pratibha Sakti...

Im trying to collect everything in Hinduism, which would help a Student, by far I have got Mantras only like(Saraswati, Prajnya Stotra)... I want to read if Hinduism has anything about, Memory, Working Memory, Imagination, Comprehension, Intelligence..etc..

Hinduism is pretty huge, and when I search online I cant get useful result..For that I need specific terms/ concept names, Which concept should I search for, if I want to learn things in Hinduism related to Memory, Intelligence, **Brain Working, Cognition, Problem Solving**..

If anyone have their research collection please share it, recently came across

```
Vidyastra - Indra kratum na aa bhara pitaa putrebhyo yathaa
```

Comment: @Panibotal No it doesnt..