# Details On Smriti, and Kalpana?

Tags: smriti, saraswati, jnana, buddhi

Please someone provide detail on Smriti, Kalpana and its working.. from Hinduism side of view..

For Example: I recently came to know about Vak, and its working.. on answer written [HERE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/what-are-four-grades-stages-or-types-of-v%C4%81k)

Im looking for details of Smriti - Memory, Jnana - Knowledge, Buddhi - Intellect, Kalpana - Imagination, Pratibha - Intelligence...

Please Please also give advice/practical tips for improving Smriti, Kalpana, Vak

Reference Questions [ONE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8013/what-is-vaak-shudddi/8023#8023) [TWO](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36795/what-are-four-grades-stages-or-types-of-v%C4%81k) [THREE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/how-to-increase-memory) [FOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42461/practices-for-focus-concentration-memory)